# how to create a check_box_tag in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have model `restaurant` and `lunch`. Where restaurant `has_many :lunches` and lunch `belongs_to :restaurant`. Having these relations, I want to show all the available restaurants as checkboxes.

lunch.rb looks like this:

```
  attr_accessible :date, :email, :name, :restaurant_id
  belongs_to :restaurant
```

but I am finding it hard to do it. Can someone explain all the params that are there for in check_box_tag?

I got a snippet of code and modified accordingly, but it doesnt work.

```
<div class="form_row">
    <label for="restaurant_id[]">Restaurants:</label>
    <% for restaurant in Restaurant.find(:all) do %>
      <br><%= check_box_tag 'restaurant_id[]', restaurant.id %>
      <%= restaurant.name.humanize %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

but when I see the log the `restaurant_id` is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the involved form helper doc:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box

```
<%= check_box_tag(:restaurant, restaurant.id) %>
```

outputs:

```
<input id="restaurant" name="restaurant" type="checkbox" value=restaurant.id />
```

The first parameter to check_box_tag, of course, is the name of the input. The second parameter, naturally, is the value of the input. This value will be included in the form data (and be present in params) when the checkbox is checked.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Source code:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb, line 929
      def check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")
        Tags::CheckBox.new(object_name, method, self, checked_value, unchecked_value, options).render
      end
```

Comment: yes but the restaurant_id values has to be come from another model, `restaurant` model

Answer (score 0):

You can't use checkbox tag if you have this association :

- restaurant has_many :lunches
- lunch belongs_to :restaurant

You should use select tag (singel select) or radio button tag on lunch form because lunch have only one restaurant.

Example using select :

```
<%= f.label :restaurant_id, 'Restaurant Name' %>
<%= f.collection_select(:restaurant_id, Restaurant.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Please select restaurant') %>
```